# Get the value of a datepicker inside of a ng-repeater

Tags: angularjs

I have a datepicker inside of a repeater. Now I need to get the value of the datepicker in my insert function. Everything I try results in 'undefined'. What is the right way to handle this?

```
<div ng-repeat="r in results | filter:searchText">
        <input class="input-datum sdate" ng-model="selecting.sdate" datepicker placeholder="datum van" />
        <input class="input-datum edate" ng-model="selecting.edate" placeholder="datum tot"/>        
        <img src="img/save.png" width="20px" class="icon" ng-click="insertTarief(selecting)"/>
</div>
```

controller:

```
var app = angular.module('DienstenApp', []);

(function () {
    app.controller('DienstenController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            var data = {
                dienstenEdit: 'get',
            };
            $http.post('ajax_crud.php', data).
                    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.results = data;
                    });

            $scope.insertTarief = function (selectValue) {
                console.log(selectValue);
            };

        }]).directive('datepicker', function ($timeout) {
    var linker = function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $(element).datepicker({
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                onSelect: function (y, instance) {
                    var edate = element.siblings('.edate');
                    edate.datepicker();
                    edate.datepicker('option', 'minDate', element.datepicker("getDate"));
                }
            });
        });
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        transclude: true,
        link: linker
    };    
   });
})();
```

Comment: how you are binding the data in datepicker?

Comment: it's not really clear what the issue you are experiencing is at this point.  I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XgnqUHyzNS6isbBdCxpS?p=preview) to attempt to recreate your issue (omitting the `$http.post` call), and though the `datepicker` directive is broken, the `insertTarief` button definitely works properly.

Comment: my first guess is that something isn't right with this `datepicker` directive, though I can't really identify what it's supposed to be doing.  If your code isn't working the same way the plunker I created is, you should create a complete example with all the relevant libraries to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the 'selecting.sdate' inside the ng-repeat, all the datepicker points to the same model. May be you need a array of model selecting.sdate[$index].

```
                Pass the 'selecting.sdate[$index]' from the view. Get the value in controller.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When i pass: ng-click="insertTarief(selecting.sdate[$index]) It still outputs undefined. The $index sounds like logic though...

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<div ng-repeat="r in results | filter:searchText track by $index">
        <input class="input-datum sdate" ng-model="selecting.sdate[$index]" datepicker placeholder="datum van" />
        <input class="input-datum edate" ng-model="selecting.edate[$index]" placeholder="datum tot"/>        
        <img src="img/save.png" width="20px" class="icon" ng-click="insertTarief($index)"/>
</div>
```

and in controller

```
 $scope.insertTarief = function (index) {
                console.log(selecting[index]);
            };
```

Comment: @Daniel did you make the change to the HTML as well as the JavaScript? because in your update to your question you only changed the JavaScript.

Comment: can you do change in your code like this code  http://plnkr.co/edit/6iZSIBa9S1G95pIMBRBu?p=preview

Comment: can    you provide results array

Answer (score -1):

```
<div ng-repeat="r in results | filter:searchText">
    <input class="input-datum sdate" ng-model="selecting.sdate" datepicker placeholder="datum van" id="{{selecting.sdate}}"/>
    <input class="input-datum edate" ng-model="selecting.edate" placeholder="datum tot"/>        
    <img src="img/save.png" width="20px" class="icon" ng-click="insertTarief(selecting)" id="{{selecting.edate}}"/>
```

> add an id field like above . 
>   and access it like this var aa = $('#'+foo.edate).val();

Comment: this is definitely not the angular way, and shouldn't be necessary in this case.

Comment: i had a simmilar prob .. jquery helped me fix it .

Comment: you may have found a non angular way to fix the problem by using jQuery, but one of the design principles of angular is to not use other libraries like jQuery.  This is a problem that *can* be solved using angular, without another library.